# Clear Spinner on Button press

Tags: android, android-spinner

Can anyone suggest how to clear the values in the spinner on a button click?

```
Spinner spinner1;
private static final String[] SpinArray= { "00", "01", "02",
        "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13",
        "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "00" };


adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            SpinArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new mySpinnerListener());

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,  
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            spinner1=parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;

    }
```

on button click i tried to clear using

```
spinner1.setAdapter(null); and spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
```

both of these didn't work in my case.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spinner1.getAdapter().clear();` should do the trick.

As Eric said in the comments, call `spinner1.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` after that.

Comment: You may also have to call `.notifyDataSetChanged()` after this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Onclicking the button, I cleared the arraylist and make a spinner adapter null.

```
arrContent.clear();
spinner1.setAdapter(null);
```