# How to clear spinner when click a button in the jaredrummler spinner?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-spinner

**how to clear spinner values in this spinner library when a button clicked.**

```
      <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/et_amounts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_receiptdate" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear Spinner on Button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703181/clear-spinner-on-button-press)

Comment: @unzila ,for this library i need

Answer (score 1):

you can set the following sample in the button click listener.

materialspinner.setItems("");

Answer (score 0):

You have called spinner2List.clear(); but haven't notified the adapter by using notifyDataSetChanged(); method.